# Event for SELECT onchange with keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I have an `onchange` event on an HTML SELECT control which calls a JavaScript function. This works if I select a new option from the open list with the mouse, or if I drop down the SELECT control and then select an option with the mouse or select with the keyboard and press ENTER.

How can I get the function to run if the SELECT control is NOT open and I simply scroll up or down with the cursor keys through the various options. `onblur` does nothing and `onkeypress` result in some strange results in which values got out of sync.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `onkeyup` event will solve this:

```
<select name="theName" id="theID" onchange="javascript:theFunction();" onkeyup="javascript:theFunction();">
<option value="A">Choice A</option>
<option value="B">Choice B</option>
<option value="C">Choice C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work?